# Kotlin: tailrec makes suspend fun never ends

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I'm learning how to make coroutines work with Java libraries using CompletableFuture. Below is my code:

```
// x invokes y invokes z invokes Java client
suspend fun x(i: Int, client: FakeJavaClient): Int {

    fun z(k: Int): Int {
        println("z: $k")
        return client.query(k).get()
    }

    tailrec // with 'tailrec', the code never terminates
    suspend fun y(j: Int): Int {
        val ret = z(j)
        if (ret > 10) {
            return ret
        }

        return y(j + 1)
    }

    return y(i)
}

fun main()  {
    runBlocking {
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            FakeJavaClient().use { x(0, it) }
        }
    }
    println("Done")
}

class FakeJavaClient : AutoCloseable {
    private val executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)

    fun query(i: Int): CompletableFuture<Int> {
        val f = CompletableFuture<Int>()
        executor.submit {
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            f.complete(i * 2)
        }
        return f
    }

    override fun close() {
        executor.shutdown()
        executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    }
}
```

If I add the `tailrec` modifier to function `y`, the code outputs like below and never ends:

```
z: 0
z: 0
z: 0
z: 0
z: 0
...
```

If I remove `tailrec` on `y`, the code behaves as my expectation

```
z: 0
z: 1
z: 2
z: 3
z: 4
z: 5
z: 6
Done
```

Could someone kindly help me understand what happens here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a known issue: [Wrong code generated for a local tailrec suspend function](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-33836).